# How to convert the new line character to tab and then insert new line character in a loop in bash

Tags: bash, for-loop

I have some `bam` files in my input directory and for each `bam` file i want to calculate the number of mapped reads (using `Samtools view` command) and print that number along with the name of the `bam` file into a output file. Though it is working, i am not getting the output that i desired.

Here is how my code looks like

```
for file in input/*;
        do
        echo $file >> test.out;
        samtools view -F 4 $file | wc -l >> output;
        done
```

This works fine but the problem is it ouputs the name of the file and number of reads in different lines. Here is an example

```
sample_data/wgEncodeUwRepliSeqBg02esG1bAlnRep1.bam
1784867
sample_data/wgEncodeUwRepliSeqBg02esG2AlnRep1.bam
2280544
```

I tried to convert the new line characters to tab by doing this

```
for file in input/*;
            do
            echo $file >> output;
            samtools view -F 4 $file | wc -l >> output;
            tr '\n' '\t' < output > output2
            done
```

Here is the output for the same

```
sample_data/wgEncodeUwRepliSeqBg02esG1bAlnRep1.bam      1784867 sample_data/wgEncodeUwRepliSeqBg02esG2AlnRep1.bam       2280544
```

How can now i insert the new line character after each line? For example

```
sample_data/wgEncodeUwRepliSeqBg02esG1bAlnRep1.bam      1784867     
sample_data/wgEncodeUwRepliSeqBg02esG2AlnRep1.bam       2280544
```

Thanks

Comment: why don't you build the line? `echo -e "$file\t$var"`, where `$var` contains the output of `samtools view...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get the desired output by writing everything in one line. Something like:

```
echo -e "$file\t$(samtools view -F 4 $file | wc -l)" >> output;
```

If you want to do it in two pieces, note that `echo` has a `-n` option to suppress trailing newlines, and `-e` to interpret escapes like `\t`, so you could do:

```
echo -ne "$file\t" >> $output
samtools view -F 4 $file | wc -l >> output
```

Writing what you want the first time is cleaner than trying to post-process your output.

Answer (score 1):

If the output of every file definitely consists of a filename and a number, I think you can easily change

```
tr '\n' '\t' < output > output2
```

to

```
tr '\n' '\t' < output | sed -r 's/([0-9]+\t)/\1\n/' > output2
```

It will match the number followed by a tab and add a new line character afterwards.

Comment: Worked very well. Yes the output is the same for all the files. How did i forgot the power of `sed`. By the way what is `\1` doing there? Is it for capturing groups similar to `R`? Thanks..

Comment: Yes, `\1` refers to the first component matched, which is ([0-9]+\t) that a bracket was used to enclose it. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Just use a command substitution:

```
for file in input/*
do
    printf '%s\t%d\n' "$file" "$(samtools view -F 4 $file | wc -l)"
done >> output
```